# "The collection was unreferenced" .Hibernate filter on an entity list by a column name?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, hibernate-mapping, query-expressions

Im getting this **Prescription List** from mysql db and what I want to do is , to **filter the list by patient_id** and get the filtered list.

I'm getting the **prescriptions** list **finely**.But I'm unable to get the **filterList**.
Following is my code.

```
@Override
    @Transactional
    public List<Prescription> retrieveAllPrescriptionsByPatientId(int id) {
        Session session=sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        List<Prescription>prescriptions = session.createCriteria(Prescription.class).list() ;   
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<Prescription> filterList =(List<Prescription>) session.createFilter(prescriptions, "where patient_Id = :id").setInteger("id", id).list();

        return (List<Prescription>)filterList;
    }
```

This is the exception I'm getting.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.QueryException: The collection was unreferenced
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.getFilterQueryPlan(SessionImpl.java:1483)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createFilter(SessionImpl.java:1330)
    at com.tela.pms.dao.impl.PrescriptionDAOImpl.retrieveAllPrescriptionsByPatientId(PrescriptionDAOImpl.java:63)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:318)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy19.retrieveAllPrescriptionsByPatientId(Unknown Source)
    at com.tela.pms.service.impl.PrescriptionServiceImpl.retrieveAllPrescriptionsByPatientId(PrescriptionServiceImpl.java:47)
    at com.tela.pms.Test.HibernateTester.main(HibernateTester.java:45)
```

Please help me out with this.
Thanks

Comment: How try with `where this.patient_Id = :id`?

Comment: Not working! Still struggling for an answer